# Which Wordpress file do I need to edit?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am tearing what's left of my hair out with this one! I am developing a Wordpress site and need to swap some pieces of information over on the page but for the life of me have no idea which file to edit. Whatever I try to do just won't work.
The URL is https://www.paultaylor.pl/clients/undercover-city-games/games/ and I need to swap the title and the location the other way round so that the location is above the BOOK NOW button and the title is below.
Any friendly genius people that may be able to help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find answer here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
Example if "games" is custom post type  search file single.php or single-games.php